# Inferring return type from createSelector factory

Tags: typescript, redux, reselect

I'm trying to integrate reselect into some redux connected components. According to the docs for reselect (https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#sharing-selectors-with-props-across-multiple-component-instances), when dealing with props passed in, to ensure the selector is properly memoized, you basically create a factory function for `createSelector`, so every component calling `connect()` gets its own selector with its own memoized state. This makes sense, and I have it working in TypeScript:

```ts
interface UploadProfileOwnProps {
    someValue: string;
}

const getUploadProfile = (state: AppState, props: UploadProfileOwnProps): UploadProfileState => state.uploadProfile;
const getCustomer = (state: AppState, props: UploadProfileOwnProps): CustomerState => state.customer;

const uploadProfileSelectorFactory = () => createSelector(getCustomer, getUploadProfile, 
    (customerState, profile)=>({
        customerId: customerState.customerId,
        ...profile
    }));

type uploadProfileSelectorProps = ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof uploadProfileSelectorFactory>>;

const connectUploadProfile = connect(()=>{
    const selector = uploadProfileSelectorFactory();
    const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState, props: UploadProfileOwnProps): uploadProfileSelectorProps =>{
        return selector(state, props);
    };
    return mapStateToProps;
}, UploadProfileActions);
```

The `OwnProps` is just a placeholder, the state doesn't depend on it at all in this case, but in others it might. The double `ReturnType<ReturnType<>>` construct bugs me a bit, but it gets the job done. Now, the actual question:

`uploadProfileSelectorFactory` lacks an explicit return type. I have eslint configured to yell at me in that case. How can I convince TypeScript to tell it that the factory function's return type is whatever `createSelector()` returns? It does properly infer the return type, so it's not causing any issues outside of eslint being cranky. I see a few options:

1. Just tell eslint to ignore the return type requirement for that line. While easiest, I don't really like it.
2. Explicitly define the type that comes out of the combiner function, then have the factory function return the type of `CreateSelector`, which in this case would be a rather messy `OutputParametricSelector<S, P, T, (res1: R1, res2: R2) => T>` that I would have to remember to change if I add another selector.
3. Somehow convince TypeScript to give me the return type of `createSelector()` without actually calling it. This might be able to be done with explicitly defining the return type of the combiner function, although I haven't tried it. This would probably also get rid of the `ReturnType<ReturnType<>>` business, at the cost of having me keep the combiner function and its return type in sync.
4. Throw `re-reselect` or similar into the mix, and hope it doesn't have that issue.
5. Invoke some TypeScript black magic that solves the whole thing.

I'm hoping for some combination of 5 and 3, although I'll take 4 if needed. Unfortunately every example I've found just uses type inference and never deals with this.

Answer (score 1):

You *do* know what `createSelector` returns, because ultimately it's just a selector that selects the `customerId` and `profile`.  The selectors created by reselect have to extra properties like `recomputations` and `resetRecomputations`, but these don't matter for the purposes of react-redux.  We just want to know what arguments the selector takes and what it returns.

This is what you are selecting:

```
type Selected = UploadProfileState & Pick<CustomerState, 'customerId'>
```

So you can use that instead of `ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof uploadProfileSelectorFactory>>`

The return type of `uploadProfileSelectorFactory` would be:

```
(state: AppState, props: UploadProfileOwnProps) => Selected;
```

But that is long-winded and we have those same two arguments in multiple places, so if you want to you could define a helper type:

```
type UploadProfileSelector<Return> = (state: AppState, props: UploadProfileOwnProps) => Return;
```

or more generalized:

```
type ComponentSelector<Props, Return> = (state: AppState, props: Props) => Return;
type UploadProfileSelector<Return> = ComponentSelector<UploadProfileOwnProps, Return>;
```

Which you can use as the return type:

```
const uploadProfileSelectorFactory = (): UploadProfileSelector<Selected> =>
```